# PHP Loop through results and output html table tr and td issue

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to generate html table columns and rows by looping through mysql results. Rows and cols defined within the variables $row_count and $col_count:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = {$id}";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows) {
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $row_count = $row->rows;
    $col_count = $row->cols;
    $fields = $row->fields;
    $data = json_decode($fields);

    foreach($data as $value) {
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';

        for($i = 0; $i < $col_count; $i++){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
}
$result->free();
}
```

As of now this outputs something like:

```
 <table>
 <td>row1-data1</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row1-data2</td></tr><tr></tr>      <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row1-data3</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row1-data4</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row2-data1</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row2-data2</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row2-data3</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>row2-data4</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr>        </table>
```

All of the data should not go into one table row but into multiple rows based on the value of $row_count.

Comment: You should echo the "<tr>" tag BEFORE the "foreach", and the closing "</tr>" AFTER the foreach.

Comment: All of the data should not go into one table row but into multiple rows based on the value of $row_count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split array per row by column count and gather back with tags

```
$chunk = array_chunk($data, $col_count);

foreach ($chunk as $row) 
  echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $row) . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: array_chunk! that's genius. Thank you. This works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you put the `tr` tags in the loop like that. `tr` wraps all the `td` tags.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    ...
    foreach($data as $value) {
        echo '<td>', $value, '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Also, you need to escape `$_GET['id']`

Edit:

Each element needs to go into a `$row_count` x `$col_count` block in the table? I misunderstood the question. What about this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    ...
    $i = 0;
    for ($r = 0; $r < $row_count; $r++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($c = 0; $c < col_count; $c++,) {
            echo '<td>', $data[$i++], '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: All of the data should not go into one table row but into multiple rows based on the value of $row_count.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this ?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = {$id}";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $row_count = $row->rows;
        $col_count = $row->cols;
        $fields = $row->fields;
        $data = json_decode($fields);

        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($data as $value) {
           echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo "</tr>";
   }
   $result->free();
}
```